# Json handling of list

Tags: json, python-3.x

Guys where I get multiple data each in a list from a database and append this to another list,so my data looks this way

```
data= [["a","b","c"],["1","2","3"]]
```

If I try to Json dump and load this data it give an error on the load side

```
import json


data2 = str.encode(json.dumps(data))
st = bytes.decode(data2)
msg = json.loads(st)

raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s,err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

But this doesn't not happen where it is a single list

Comment: Please show the code you are using to convert the results of the database query to JSON. Also, what do you mean by "if this list includes an image"? In what way is the image "included"?

Comment: You have are missing a double quote before the SELECT, is this a error in you copying it or the error you are encountering

Comment: @kaledaiwave that's just a typing error,there could b more as am using my phone to type this,but be assured it has nothing to do with syntax error

Comment: I pasted same code, with ```json.load```, it worked fine. Python version 3.7.4    
```>>> data= [["a","b","c"],["1","2","3"]]
>>>
>>> import json
>>>
>>>
>>> data2 = str.encode(json.dumps(data))
>>> st = bytes.decode(data2)
>>> msg = json.loads(st)
>>>
>>> with open("tst.json", 'w') as f:
...    json.dump(msg, f, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(',', ': '))
...
>>>```

Comment: Thank you all guys I found a way around it,though it's not the best,turns out Json.load has issues with a list that contains too many list with  too many items in each,so after dumping, it cannot load it,I would like to know why json behaves like this,this has made my job more difficult,cos now where I have an sql TABLE  with 100columns.instead of using a sql statement (SELECT * FROM TABLE),in other to avoid json error I have to get it in smaller chunks (SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM TABLE)